# Invert colors of an image in CSS or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, colors

How do I invert colors of an image (jpg/png..) in either css if possible or javascript?

[Previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12431710/inverting-colors-in-part-of-an-image-html-css-js) [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5735722/invert-image-color-onmouseover) questions don't give enough detail.

Comment: You can use html5 canvas. See [this tutorial](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-invert-image-colors-tutorial/).

Answer (score 191, accepted):

CSS3 has a new filter attribute <del>which will only work in webkit browsers</del> [supported](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-filters) in webkit browsers and in Firefox. It does not have support in IE or Opera mini:

```css
img {
   -webkit-filter: invert(1);
   filter: invert(1);
   }
```

```html
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/1H91A5Y.png">
```

Comment: Not working in Firefox 16.0.2. But [here](http://forum.userstyles.org/discussion/32770/inverting-map-images/p1) I found this could work : `filter: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2Z...<long address>...PC9zdmc+#invert);`, could it?

Comment: Well that is because firefox is not webkit. You would need to do a check if browser is webkit, else do your inversion via base64 conversion.

Comment: You're right, it does work in Chrome. I'm pretty sure this should work in Firefox as said [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/filter): `filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg height='0' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'><filter id='blur'><feGaussianBlur stdDeviation='5' /></filter></svg>");` but it doesn't... any ideas?

Comment: Nice, but it is very crashy. It inverts the colors but when I move the mouse over my page the tab crashes. Tried it with Google Chrome 25.0.1364.172 x86_64 Linux.

Comment: As a side note one may consider the contrast(0.1)` filter.

Answer (score 11):

Can be done in major new broswers using the code below

```
.img {
    -webkit-filter:invert(100%);
     filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(invert='1');
}
```

However, if you want it to work across all browsers you need to use Javascript. Something like [this gist](https://gist.github.com/paulirish/373253) will do the job.

Answer (score 4):

You can apply the style via javascript. This is the Js code below that applies the filter to the image with the ID theImage.

```
function invert(){
document.getElementById("theImage").style.filter="invert(100%)";
}
```

And this is the

```
<img id="theImage" class="img-responsive" src="http://i.imgur.com/1H91A5Y.png"></img>
```

Now all you need to do is call invert() We do this when the image is clicked.

```js
function invert(){
document.getElementById("theImage").style.filter="invert(100%)";
}
```

```html
<h4> Click image to invert </h4>

<img id="theImage" class="img-responsive" src="http://i.imgur.com/1H91A5Y.png" onClick="invert()" ></img>
```

We use this on our [website](http://www.veed.io)

Answer (score 0):

For inversion from 0 to 1 and back you can use this library [InvertImages](https://github.com/shekhardesigner/InvertImages), which provides support for IE 10. I also tested with IE 11 and it should work.