# Can we convert a black and white image to reverse effect with CSS

Tags: image, css

Well I wish to add a cool effect to black and white images wherein the color changes to white black on hover that is the white parts become black and black becomes white.

I know one method of using image hover effects by adding a second similar image with the desired color effect and when someone hovers the second image shows up but I wish to know if we can do it by using CSS filters. For the first image I used greyscale css filter but I wish to know if there is another effect which can reverse the black and white colors in the greyscale effect to white and black colors. Many Thanks in Advance. :)

Comment: This might be of use to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13325798/invert-colors-of-an-image-in-css-or-javascript

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best way to go about this with just CSS would be to chain together greyscale and then invert attribute as mentioned by 2C-B, like so -

```
-webkit-filter: grayscale(1) invert(1);
filter: grayscale(1) invert(1);
```