# Changing Background Color in Rstudio

Tags: rstudio

Is it possible to change the background colors in Rstudio? I know it's possible to change the theme of the editor, which is a really nice feature and which I'm already using, but is it possible to change the background color of the other windows (Environment, History, Files, etc...) to something else than white and the text to something darker? Backgrounds that are too light give me a headache.

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It isn't, but if you're running Linux, you can have the window manager invert the color of just one window. Target this to the RStudio window and you'll get RStudio with an inverse theme. (This was a common trick employed with Eclipse until it got a dark theme with the release of Eclipse Luna.)

https://askubuntu.com/questions/134668/how-to-trigger-a-color-inversion-effect-for-one-window

Comment: Obviously, this solution wouldn't work for people like me, who use RStudio Server :-(. RStudio team really should make RStudio UI customization easier and fuller (I hope that @hadley will read this).

Comment: If you're using RStudio through a web browser, you could style the content with a user agent stylesheet or browser extension, although this would be an arduous task indeed--RStudio uses hundreds of CSS selectors, with names obfuscated by its UI toolkit, [GWT](http://www.gwtproject.org/). And you're talking to the RStudio team. :-) Better UI customizability is a long-standing request and one we'd love to do when we have the resources.

Comment: Jonathan, thank you for your comment. I didn't realize that I'm talking to a member of The Team :-). I briefly thought about trying to play with RStudio's CSS stuff, but quickly abandoned this idea even without knowing the true complexity of it, as you describe. Trying to finish a Ph.D. dissertation doesn't give me the luxury to pay attention to aesthetics, I need first to get the essence right...

Comment: Do you think it's possible for RStudio Server users to exploit, depending on their preferred browser, **this** (http://stackoverflow.com/a/13325820/2872891) or **this** (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter) to "make" a dark theme? I just spent some time and tried to do it in various places, like `/usr/lib/rstudio-server/www`, but so far unsuccessfully. It would help to know where to look and what to change... ;-). I guess, I haven't abandoned this idea completely...

Comment: @Jonathan Is it possible to include a dark overall interface option in one of the next updates of RStudio? The light interface with dark code panel looks ugly.

Comment: @Ilya, it's one of our most common feature requests. A big challenge is updating all of the art to look nice on a dark background -- if you've ever tried the dark theme on Eclipse, it looks terrible because they didn't do this. We'll do it right when we do it. :-)

Comment: @Jonathan, no offense)) I think, this must be the most anticipated aesthetics thing. But thanks for RStudio, it's marvelous.

Comment: @Jonathan - A simple idea for the dark theme is making it available for all but the plot section (keep it white as current) if this would make the implementation of dark theme easier instead of put it on hold forever.

Answer (score 5):

### Edit:

### Hi all

### [since this is work in progress and i don't want to update this post all the time i moved the project to GitHub. Fell free to download the files from there.](https://github.com/SWolf23/rstudio-darkTheme.git)

The issues with dropdown menu, autocomplete and popups are solved in the latest Version on GitHub. Still newer builds than version 1.0.143 are not supported. But i will work on it.

---

Edit (05.05.2017): My custom_style.css works with the actual stable Version of RStudio 1.0.143 .
[Newer Preview and Daily Builds got already an upgrade where you can choose out of 3 different Themes.](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/203842428-Getting-the-newest-RStudio-builds) My files don't work with these newer builds at the moment, but I am working on it.
Cause only one of these themes is kind of a dark metal blue but not the dark them i want to have. I will upload it as soon as it works.

I tested my theme yesterday on a Lubuntu 17.04 OS.
Here are the Install instructions for Linux:
Enter your installation folder for rstudio

```
cd /usr/lib/rstudio
```

Copy the [Dark Theme folder you downloaded](https://github.com/SWolf23/rstudio-darkTheme.git) to the rstudio install dir

```
sudo cp -avrf /home/<user>/Downloads/RStudioDarkStyle ./
```

First save the Original files to a new folder (vanilla) if something goes wrong

```
sudo mkdir vanilla
sudo cp -avrf ./www/index.htm                   ./vanilla/index.htm
sudo cp -avrf ./resources/R.css                 ./vanilla/R.css
sudo cp -avrf ./resources/grid/gridstyles.css   ./vanilla/gridstyles.css
```

If you set own styles before you can also save them if u don't have this may result in an error.

```
sudo cp -avrf ./www/custom_styles.css           ./vanilla/custom_styles.css
```

Then we replace the original files with the new ones

```
sudo cp -avrf ./RStudioDarkStyle/index.htm          ./www/index.htm 
sudo cp -avrf ./RStudioDarkStyle/custom_styles.css  ./www/custom_styles.css 
sudo cp -avrf ./RStudioDarkStyle/R.css              ./resources/R.css 
sudo cp -avrf ./RStudioDarkStyle/gridstyles.css     ./resources/grid/gridstyles.css
```

And thats all it should work now.

---

I found [this guide how to make rstudio dark by zencoder on rstudio support](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000437028-Dark-style-for-R-Studio-IDE?page=1#community_comment_115003429047)

and improved it a little bit.

[image: R-Studio-Dark]

I edited the custom_styles.css and the gridstyles.css the other files are original as zencoder wrote them.

For Installation guide see the readme file.
I use the "Vibrant Ink" Apperance with it on a Win7 pc.

I didn't even try to change the plot window, because most graphics are used in papers and such and are normaly printed with a white background, for me it is more functional to have a white background for plots.

Have fun with this hope it helps.

DdS

Comment: Instead of posting a link to your other answer, post the relevant content of it here. If both questions have the exact same answer, consider flagging one of them as duplicate instead of reposting your own answer.

Comment: To mark as a duplicate, click on the flag link below the question.

Comment: I don't have the privelege to flag posts yet.

Comment: Fair enough. I've voted to close the other one as a duplicate.

Comment: It would be nice that topmost bar also were dark.

Answer (score 4):

It's simple now.

```
Tools > Options > Appearance
```

Choose color.

That's it.